# Normal ring and unmixed ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative Gorenstein local ring , $I$ an ideal of $R$ . If $R/I$ is normal ring , then for any $p \in \operatorname{Ass_{R}}(R/I)$, $\operatorname{ht}(p)=  \operatorname{ht}(I)$?

Comment: Thank you. Very easy.... .I use the usual definition. As you say I is prime, it is trivial....